# Problem with linux command on grub console and debian livecd-6.0.10-i386

Tags: linux, debian, boot, grub

I'm trying to boot a [Debian 6.0.10-i386 LiveCD](https://chuangtzu.ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage/archive/6.0.10-live/i386/usb-hdd/debian-live-6.0.10-i386-xfce-desktop.img) using grub 2.04.16 installed on efi partition created with recent debian installer: laptop is an old macbookpro1,1 (2006, 32bit), the livecd is cloned via dd on a usb key.
When I start pc I enter the grub console and try to load linux from usb key: I set root (`set root=(hd2,msdos1)`) and when I give `linux /live/vmlinux root=/dev/sda1` the console freezes.

PS I'm doing this weird thing because I'm following this interesting post on how, between other stuff, extract VESA BIOS: [Archlinux on a MacBook Pro 15'' Model A1211](http://www.andreasbaumann.cc/blog/archlinux-macbook-a1211/), and as far as I understood I need an old kernel (for example one shipped with ubuntu10 which seems to be Linux 2.6.39) so I chose a debian release around the release of Linux 2.6.39, the one shipped with more or less Ubuntu 10.

Much appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks!